# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi \mathrm en!)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi \mathrm en!)$$

Comment: Sentences "evaluate $x$" won't help you receive advises from people. Especially if you use exclamation marks. What have you tried?

Comment: @Ilya: I have tried but cannot find anything.

Comment: Hint: What is the closest integer to $en!$?

Comment: I can tell the answer to the question is $2\pi$. I dont know how to do it. Help!

Comment: @Ilya: not sure if you were being facetious, but the exclamation mark is a factorial, not an emotional outburst.

Comment: @rlgordonma: neither I'm sure, but in a way OP is stated, it's more likely to be an exclamation mark (which fits better the style) than the factorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: If you write $${\rm e}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1\over k!}$$then $${\rm e}n!=({\rm integer})+{1\over n+1}+({\rm small\ number})$$

Comment: I think if we solve using this result we will get answer $2\pi$.